# How do i get access to this array, vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

How do I get access to this array, inside it has objects, I used `laravel`, `inertiajs`, `vuejs`, Im passing the variable from laravel controller to vuejs component with inertia.js

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7yjL.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ROZ.png]

```
  public function index($slug,Category $categories)
    {
        $category = $categories->where('slug',$slug)->with('product')->get();

        return Inertia::render('Category',[
            'categories' => $category
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your point correctly , I think you would like to access the products , then it's better to return from the controller to vue only the products.
and according to the variable naming I think you are expecting only one category to be returned then may be you need to check retrieving single model using `->first()`
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 0):

You can loop with v-for or access directly:

```
categories[0].description
```